# Sideways forces on submerged masses

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, pressure, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics

Imagine 2 submerged masses in a liquid that are free to move and in close proximity.   Pressure is exerted on all surfaces. Will the sideways pressure force them together? There will be equal and opposing forces on adjacent surfaces, will these be lessened/ cancel out and allow the lateral sideways forces to push them together? This is in regard to pressure forces and not gravitational forces exerted on each other. For this experiment that force is a ignored. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Are these 2 masses moving in the same direction or in opposite directions?

Comment: Interesting lateral effects can occur if the masses are only partially submerged. See "[A water wave analog of the Casimir effect](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article-abstract/77/12/1095/1042888/A-water-wave-analog-of-the-Casimir-effect?redirectedFrom=fulltext)." The reason is that wave motion is suppressed in the gap, resulting in an apparent attractive force that pulls floating objects together. This effect should be absent for macroscale objects fully submerged in still water.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the sideways pressure force them together ?

Not in general, no. The horizontal force on each object nets to zero (otherwise the object would immediately start to move sideways as soon as it was submerged). There *may* be some odd effects if the surfaces of the objects were *very* smooth and they were *very* close together (a few microns apart), but in general they will not move towards each other.

> There will be equal and opposing forces on adjacent surfaces.

Not sure why you think this. If the objects have vertical faces then the horizontal force on each vertical face will be pressure times area. If the areas are different, these forces will be different. The liquid between the objects does *not* act like a string or a spring that exerts the same magnitude force at each of its ends. The liquid exerts the same *pressure* (force per unit area) on each of the objects, but that is not the same thing.